# Drawing a dynamic graph

Tags: java, graph, graph-layout, graph-drawing

I have a web application written with [JavaServer Faces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Faces) technology.

The application takes n inputs and provides an output.

I want the following functionality in my application.

I want to have sliders for each of my inputs.

I want the output to be depicted by a graph.

So whenever I change the input values via a slider I want the changed output value also displayed in the graph

So what will be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need two components. One is the slider component which comes with pretty much every component library. 
Second one is the chart component I believe comes 
with the [PrimeFaces component library](http://www.primefaces.org/). All JavaServer Faces component libraries support [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) so you could give it a shot.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but I am already using the Trinidad and Tobago faces component which does not have a slider. So is there any work around in this case ??

Comment: RichFaces and PrimeFaces both have slider components consider using them.

Comment: But I am not using either of them but infact am using Trinidad and Tobago

Answer (score 0):

May be you could use the [Google Chart API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chart_API).

Comment: will give it a shot and get back to you

Comment: okay maybe I can use the google api for the graphs.... but what about the sliders how do i code that ??

Answer (score 0):

In one of my projects we had a similar request.

As we where using richfaces we used those components but for the graph drawing we used **[jGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/)**, a small 'open source' library.

We chose jGraph as it was the only (not too expensive) library we found that allowed us to **layout automatically a graph**. (automatic layout is part of a licensed version, not free)

We used the richfaces **mediaoutput** component to call our backingbean which used jGraph to render a jpg of our graph.